# Textfield type date get year only in React

Tags: reactjs, date, uitextfield

Does any one know how to get only the year using the Textfield type date in react?

```
 <TextField
                key={"input-year"}
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                required
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                type="date"
                label="Year"
                margin="dense"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={formValues?.year}
              />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code according to requirement. Please check

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select } from '@mui/material';

const App = () => {
  const years = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => new Date().getFullYear() - index);
    return (
      <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" margin="dense">
         <InputLabel htmlFor="year">Year</InputLabel>
         <Select
           label="Year"
           value={formValues?.year}
           onChange={handleChange}
           inputProps={{
               name: 'year',
               id: 'year',
           }}
         >
           {years.map((year) => (
             <MenuItem key={year} value={year}>
               {year}
             </MenuItem>
           ))}
       </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}

export default App;
```

You can manage year logic according to your requirement.

Comment: I intended for the selector to only show years, and not the full calender

Comment: So in this case, you need to write custom code because there is no type for selecting only years. But we can achieve this with simple logic of year dropdown with whatever limit we want.

Comment: @Caeser, You can now check updated code above. Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this was helpful, I used the years const with the material UI Textfield and got the desired outcome. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using JavaScript's string manipulation functions.In the handleChange function, event.target.value will give you the selected date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. By using split('-'), you can split this string into an array where the first element is the year.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const selectedYear = event.target.value.split('-')[0];
    console.log(selectedYear);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      key={"input-year"}
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
      required
      fullWidth
      variant="outlined"
      type="date"
      label="Year"
      margin="dense"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={formValues?.year}
    />
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```